# How do we send data via GET method?

Tags: http, blackberry, https, get

I am creating a HTTPS connection and setting the request property as GET:

```
_httpsConnection = (HttpsConnection) Connector.open(URL, Connector.READ_WRITE);
_httpsConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpsConnection.GET);
```

But how do I send the GET parameters?
Do I set the request property like this:

```
_httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("method", "session.getToken");
_httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("developerKey", "value");
_httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("clientID", "value");
```

or do I have to write to the output stream of the connection?

or do I need to send the Parameter/Values by appending it to the url?

Comment: I'm not blackberry developer. But You can easy test your code using network sniffer (IMO overkill) or simple server side script that will just output info of your request. For example in php you can use: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `Connection.setRequestProperty()` will set the request header, which probably isn't what you want to do in this case (if you ask me I think calling it *setRequestHeader* would have been a better choice).  Some proxies may strip off or rewrite the name of non-standard headers, so you're better off sticking to the convention of passing data in the GET URL via URL parameters.

The best way to do this on a BlackBerry is to use the `URLEncodedPostData` class to properly encode your URL parameters:

```
URLEncodedPostData data = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8", false);
data.append("method", "session.getToken");
data.append("developerKey", "value");
data.append("clientID", "value");
url = url + "?" + data.toString();
```

Answer (score 6):

`HTTP GET` send data parameters as key/value pairs encoded within URL, just like:

```
GET /example.html                      // without parameters
GET /example.html?Id=         1        // with one basic parameter
GET /example.html?Id=1&Name=John%20Doo // with two parameters, second encoded
```

Note follow rules for character separators:

```
? - split URL in two pieces: adddress to left and paremeters to right
& - must be used to separate on parameter from another
```

You must know your platform specific native string encode function. Javascript uses `escape`, C# uses `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`

Answer (score 2):

Yep, headers and properties are pretty much all you can send in a GET. Also, you're limited to a certain number of characters, which is browser dependent - I seem to recall about 1024 or 2000, typically.

Comment: Hey do I need to send the Parameter/Values via the header or just append it to the url

Comment: you can just append it to the url

Comment: No idea how your environment works, but in the end your request parameters will be included in the URL. You can either do this directly (use & to separate key/value pairs, = between key and value, URL-escape characters in strings) or hopefully let your API do that stuff for you automagically.